# angular cookies and counting the amount times that user comes to my site

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I wanna be able to show an overlay after a user comes to my site more then three times.

I've set a cookie call 'cookie' with a value of false.

After a user visits my page 3 time how do i set it to true?

Comment: $cookies.put(val, true). You should check cookies every time when user comes to your site. Here is doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use an integer you will increment until it is 3. If you haven't logged the number of previous visits, there's no way to guess when the site is visited for the 3rd time.

```
var visited = $cookie.get('visited');

if (visited) { // there's a cookie
  if (visited < 3) {
    $cookies.put('visited', visited + 1);
  } else { 
    // here we display the banner
  }
} else {
  $cookies.put('visited', 1);
}
```

Comment: It seems not to be counting up on each page load

Comment: @ronoc4 How do you define page load? if you are using ngRoute for example you are probably in a single-page-application where full reloads are not meant to happen during use and a global controller will not be reloaded when you navigate the site

Comment: Didnt think of that, How could I test it then?

Comment: @ronoc4 it would be heavy to do precisely what you asked for, it would probably need a service called by your views' controller. Wouldn't a `setTimeout()` based solution be enough?